# What does 'back' mean in a sentence

Tags: american-english, syntactic-analysis

First, are the following sentences correct (i,e no awkwardness there)? :

> All the time I spent studying for my master's degree **back** in the US, I
>   didn't come back to my country
>
> All the time I spent studying for my master's degree in the US, I
>   didn't come back to my country

Second, what is the new information that the word **back** added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More idiomatic is

> All the time I was studying for my master's degree in the States, I
>   didn't [once] come back to my country.

If you use 'spent', the adverbial usage required here is at best awkward.

...

'Back' is deictic, referring to a location which you consider home or often just where you were some time ago (ie before the time spoken of). It can be used alone with a verb, directionally (She went back [to Elbonia]) or in a phrase, locatively (I was then working back in Philadelphia). Using it twice in a sentence without verbs of relocation is at best unnatural sounding, at worst confusing.

But

All the time I was studying for my master's degree back in the States, I never once visited Disneyland' is fine.

Comment: The last example makes it all clear!

Comment: What about: "All the time I spent in the US studying for my master's degree..." does it also sound awkward?  I used to use the verb 'spent' wherever there is a usage of 'time-like' sentences

Comment: It's required in "All the time I spent in the US studying for my master's degree was a marvellous investment", but here it's the subject, not a temporal adjunct.